# MongoError: unknown top level operator: $match. If you have a field name that starts with a '$' symbol, consider using $getField or $setField

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
    if(keyword){
      keywordFilterQuery =   {"$match":{$or: [{title : { $regex: keyword, $options: "i" }},{street : { $regex: keyword, $options: "i" }}],...search}}
    } else if(keyword === "" || keyword === undefined || keyword === null) {
      keywordFilterQuery= {search}
}
    if(keyword_features){
      filterQuery = {"$match":{$or: [{special_features : {$regex: keyword_features, $options: "i"}}, {facilities : {$regex: keyword_features, $options: "i"}}, {fixtures_fittings : {$regex: keyword_features, $options: "i"}}],...keywordFilterQuery}}   
    } 
      else if(keyword_features === "" || keyword_features === undefined || keyword_features === null) {
      filterQuery = keywordFilterQuery
    }

    const results = await model.aggregate([      
  
      filterQuery
])
```

If the keyword comes from the front end it must search in the MongoDB fields whether it is matching with title or street. If it is matching it will return that into keywordFilterQuery and checks whether there are keyword_features from the front end, if it matches with the field special_features or facilities it will return it to filterQuery, and then it is passed to the aggregation. This is what I needed.

But here while I am passing I got an error like this:

**
MongoError: unknown top-level operator: $match. If you have a field name that starts with a '$' symbol, consider using $getField or $setField.
**

While I am passing keywordFilterQuery directly to the aggregation, I got a result matching that.

Please help!

Comment: Have a look at generated code: `console.log(JSON.stringify(filterQuery))`

Comment: The `$match` stage here (in the `filterQuery` variable) is not being constructed correctly. You are using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) in a couple of places, but the object being included _already_ has a `$match` defined. That's why the database is complaining about an `unknown top-level **operator**: $match`. It is finding `$match` (which is a stage) when looking for operators. Consider constructing the full filter condition first and _then_ wrapping it with the `$match` at the end.